# how to calculate discrete event probability?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A bookstore sells children's books that belong to two publishing companies A and B and were published between years 2000 and 2004. The probabilities of a book being published by companies A and B are 0.6 and 0.4. The probability that company A published a book in years 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004 are 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3 and 0.1 respectively. The probability that company B published a book in years 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004 are 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2 and 0.2 respectively.

a) Find the probability that a book was published after 2002
b) Find the probability that a book published after 2002 was published by company A.

I think that for solution a)

probability that a book was published after 2002 is

$$\begin{align}
P(A \cup B) &= P(A) + P(B) - P(A)P(B)
\end{align}
$$

which is equal to

$$\begin{align}
P(A \cup B) &= \frac{4}{10}+\frac{4}{10}-\frac{4}{10}\frac{4}{10} = 0.64
\end{align}
$$

for solution b) i don't understand the question exactly but

If I assume that it asks only the probability that a book published after 2002 was published by company A

$$\begin{align}
P(A \cup \overline{B}) &= P(A) + P(\overline{B}) - P(A)P(\overline{B})
\end{align}
$$

which is equal to

$$\begin{align}
P(A \cup B) &= \frac{4}{10}+\frac{6}{10}-\frac{4}{10}\frac{6}{10} = 0.76
\end{align}
$$

Otherwise if I assume that only the probability that a book published after 2002 was published by company A and the probability that a book published after 2002 was published by company A and B

So the solution is

$$
P(A) = 4/10 = 0.4
$$

Is solution of a is correct and for b which solution is correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you see how you can convert all the probabilities to these values?

And does that make it easier to figure out the answers?

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
\text{Company}& \text{2000}& \text{2001}& \text{2002}& \text{2003}& \text{2004} \\ \hline
\text{A} & .06& .12& .18& .18& .06  \\ \hline
\text{B} & .12& .08& .04& .08& .08  \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

There is no "published by A and B".  They are mutually exclusive.  So to find part b), you need to find what percentage of books published after 2002 were the ones published by Company A.